# Why do we apply BFS/DFS in SPOJ(ALLIZWELL) ? Why would not simple brute force work?

Tags: java, breadth-first-search, depth-first-search, brute-force

[Problem Link](http://www.spoj.com/problems/ALLIZWEL/)

By brute force I mean if I take 6 variables a,l,i,w,e,z for alphabet A,L,I,W,E,Z and count their number of occurrence apply condition as:

```
if(a<1||l<4||i<1||w<1||e<1||z<2)
        {
            System.out.println("NO");

        }
        else
            System.out.println("YES");
```

What's wrong in that? 
Here's my complete code and also I'm getting wrong answer.

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class Main {

        public static void main(String asd[]) throws Exception {

            Parser in = new Parser(System.in);
            int t=in.nextInt();
            while(t-->0)
            {
                int r=in.nextInt();
                int c=in.nextInt();int a,l,i,z,w,e;
                a=l=i=z=w=e=0;
                for(int j=0;j<r;j++)
                {
                    String s=in.next();
                    for(int k=0;k<s.length();k++)
                    {
                        char ch=s.charAt(k);
                        switch(ch)
                        {
                            case 'A':a++;break;
                            case 'L':l++;break;
                            case 'I':i++;break;
                            case 'Z':z++;break;
                            case 'W':w++;break;
                            case 'E':e++;break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                if(a<1||l<4||i<1||w<1||e<1||z<2)
                {
                    System.out.println("NO");

                }
                else
                    System.out.println("YES");
            }

        }
    }
   // for inputting  
    class Parser {
        final private int BUFFER_SIZE = 1 << 16;

        private DataInputStream din;
        private byte[] buffer;
        private int bufferPointer, bytesRead;

        public Parser(InputStream in) {
            din = new DataInputStream(in);
            buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE];
            bufferPointer = bytesRead = 0;
        }

        public long nextLong() throws Exception {
            long ret = 0;
            byte c = read();
            while (c <= ' ') c = read();
            boolean neg = c == '-';
            if (neg) c = read();
            do {
                ret = ret * 10 + c - '0';
                c = read();
            } while (c > ' ');
            if (neg) return -ret;
            return ret;
        }

        //reads in the next string
        public String next() throws Exception {
            StringBuilder ret = new StringBuilder();
            byte c = read();
            while (c <= ' ') c = read();
            do {
                ret = ret.append((char) c);
                c = read();
            } while (c > ' ');
            return ret.toString();
        }

        public int nextInt() throws Exception {
            int ret = 0;
            byte c = read();
            while (c <= ' ') c = read();
            boolean neg = c == '-';
            if (neg) c = read();
            do {
                ret = ret * 10 + c - '0';
                c = read();
            } while (c > ' ');
            if (neg) return -ret;
            return ret;
        }

        private void fillBuffer() throws Exception {
            bytesRead = din.read(buffer, bufferPointer = 0, BUFFER_SIZE);
            if (bytesRead == -1) buffer[0] = -1;
        }

        private byte read() throws Exception {
            if (bufferPointer == bytesRead) fillBuffer();
            return buffer[bufferPointer++];
        }
    }
```

Comment: In most cases, the statement that brute force doesn't work is meant in practical terms (i.e. too much time). DFS/BFS try to determine which 'paths' are unnecessary to avoid wasting time checking unnecessary things. I also suggest you read the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just because the matrix contains enough letters doesn't mean there's a path that puts them all in the right order.

For a simple example, consider

AILLZZWELL

You need an L adjacent to the A, but there is none.

Have you ever played the game "Boggle?"  It's basically the same concept.

Comment: So by path, Do you mean I can go vertical / horizontal / diagonal only?

Comment: Yes.  From the problem instructions you linked: "There is a path from any cell to all its neighbouring cells. A neighbour may share an edge or a corner."